# Single parent entering Japan with 16 year old minor

Tags: japan, minors

Are there any special documents needed to enter Japan as a single, fully custody, parent of a 16 year old minor?

We will only be in Japan for 7 days on a tourist visa.

I've checked [here](http://japan.usembassy.gov/e/acs/tacs-7108b.html) and can't seem to find any information on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some quick searching, I wasn't able to turn up anything specific either. However, Japan now does subscribe to the Hague Convention. This assumes that the minor child has a passport and that the other parent is alive. So, to be safe:

1. A notarized statement from the non-custodial parent stating that you have permission to take the child out of the country, dated within 3 months of travel.

Whether or not that's possible:

2. Notarized copy of decree giving you sole/full custody.
3. A court order allowing you to take the child out of the country.

Separately:

4. Child's birth certificate that includes your name as a parent.

Comment: Obviously none of that will hurt, but I'd be astonished if you needed any of it. Japan subscribes to the "possession is nine tenths of the law" school when it comes to child custody issues.

Comment: Well, the US states that it's not needed, but that if you're asked for it, and can't produce, you'll definitely be delayed. See [this page](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/268/kw/us%20citizen%20CHILD%20TRAVELING%20ALONE/session/L3RpbWUvMTQyNzUyNDIwMS9zaWQvejJscmJxaW0%3D/suggested/1).